# Can dotnetnuke help me create a secure portal to add to my site made in Visual Studio?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I created a company website in Visual Studio / vb / .net 4.0.  I'm not an experienced programmer, but I've read things about dotnetnuke.

I'm trying to have a directory, /portal/, where employees can log in, maybe upload documents, or keep a calendar, and things like that.  Wishful thinking, but it'd be nice to have part of the portal dedicated to clients, where they could store engineering drawings or whatever.  So I'd like a protected portal where access is denied without a login and password.  Furthermore, I'd like the registration to send an email to me so I can choose personally whether or not to grant them access.

Is dotnetduke a good place to look for what I'm trying to do?  Can I integrate it into my Visual Studio website? And does dotnetnuke have a friendly GUI, where not too much complex programming is involved?   I know it seems like 3 questions, but it's really only 1.

Any link to a good open-source project for what I'm looking for, or really, any help or guidance anybody could offer in this regard would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of questions you're asking there, the simple answer to most of them is yes.

Can DNN be used to create two portals, one for customers, one for employees, to maintain a variety of documents, images, etc, yes.

Can you integrate DNN with your existing visual studio website, yes and no. DNN's content is managed through a web browser, not through visual studio. You can copy the HTML from your VS website into DNN.

You use visual studio for DotNetNuke to create custom extensions, custom functionality, designs, etc, not for managing the content itself.

I would recommend getting DotNetNuke up and running locally and give it a whirl.

Comment: Thank you for the information, Chris.  I'm downloading DNN right now, so I'm going to delve into things with what you mentioned in mind.  Thanks again for taking the time to respond!